# Replacing words in a String java

Tags: java, string, replace

Say I have a string,

```
String templatePhrase = "I have a string that needs changing";
```

I also have a method to replace words in any given String. Here is the method:

```
public String replace(String templatePhrase, String token, String wordToPut) {

    return templatePhrase.replace(token, wordToPut);

}
```

Now say (for the sake of my actual task) I have all the words in my String `str` in a List named `wordsInHashtags`. I want to loop through all the words in `wordsInHashtags` and replace them with words from another List named `replacement` using the `replace()` method. Each time the loop iterates, the modified String should be saved so it will hold its replacement(s) for the next loop.

I will post my code if anyone would like to see it, but I think it would confuse more than help, and all I am interested in is a way to save the modified String for use in the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Go ahead and post your code

Comment: What's wrong with `String temp=str; while(...) { temp = replace(temp, token, wordToPut); }`

Comment: Jim Garrison - Genius! it's been a long day.... thanks for help

Comment: I thought the problem was that if intending to replace a word "is" with "was", it doesn't change "kiss" to "kwass", which your current code will do: That is, you code doesnt repkaceceords but rather character sequences whether "words" or not. Also, I would use a Map of old-->new words.

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading about strings in beginning Java 2 the other day, :"Strings Objects are immutable" Cant be changes basically however StringBuffer Objects were created to deal with such a circumstance as i understand it. You could try:

```
StringBuffer templatePhrase = "I have a string to be changed";

templatePhrase.replace(token, wordToPut);

String replacedString = (String)templatePhrase;
```

Line 3 may cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

public class Rephrase {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /***
     Here is some code that might help to change word in string. originally this is a Question from Absolute Java 5th edition. It will change two variable whatever you want but algorithm never change.So the input from keyboard or any other input source.
     ********/
    String sentence = "I hate you";
    String replaceWord = " hate";
    String replacementWord = "love";

    int hateIndex = sentence.indexOf(replaceWord);
    String fixed = sentence.substring(0,hateIndex)+" "+replacementWord+sentence.substring(hateIndex+replaceWord.length());
     System.out.println(fixed);
}
```

}